# PHP is array or single object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have simple php code:

```
<?php

$json = '
{
  "TrackResponse": {
    "Shipment": {
      "Package": {
        "TrackingNumber": "1Z7V015Y6870100000",
        "Activity": {
          "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": {
                "City": "Caledon",
                "StateProvinceCode": "ON",
                "CountryCode": "CA"
              }
            },
            "Status": {
              "Type": "I",
              "Description": "Departed from Facility",
              "Code": "DP"
            },
            "Date": "20230322",
            "Time": "003100"
        },
        "Activity2": [
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": {
                "City": "Caledon",
                "StateProvinceCode": "ON",
                "CountryCode": "CA"
              }
            },
            "Status": {
              "Type": "I",
              "Description": "Departed from Facility",
              "Code": "DP"
            },
            "Date": "20230322",
            "Time": "003100"
          },
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": {
                "City": "Caledon",
                "StateProvinceCode": "ON",
                "CountryCode": "CA"
              }
            },
            "Status": {
              "Type": "I",
              "Description": "Arrived at Facility",
              "Code": "AR"
            },
            "Date": "20230321",
            "Time": "115000"
          },
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": {
                "City": "Windsor",
                "StateProvinceCode": "ON",
                "CountryCode": "CA"
              }
            },
            "Status": {
              "Type": "I",
              "Description": "Departed from Facility",
              "Code": "DP"
            },
            "Date": "20230320",
            "Time": "180900"
          }

        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$activity = $data['TrackResponse']['Shipment']['Package']['Activity'];
$activity2 = $data['TrackResponse']['Shipment']['Package']['Activity2'];

if (is_object($activity)) {
    print_r(' Activity is an object ');
} else {
    print_r(' Activity is NOT an object ');
}

if (is_array($activity)) {
    print_r(' Activity is an array ');
} else {
    print_r(' Activity is NOT an array ');
}

if (is_object($activity2)) {
    print_r(' Activity2 is an object ');
} else {
    print_r(' Activity2 is NOT an object ');
}

if (is_array($activity2)) {
    print_r(' Activity2 is an array ');
} else {
    print_r(' Activity2 is NOT an array ');
}



?>
```

Activity could be single object like "Activity" in json or could be array of objects like "Activity2" and I need to indicate if Activity is an array or it's single object. I try to use is_array function, but it always returns true, despite it's single object. count($activity) for returns 4 (wrong), count for ($activity2) = 3, correct. How to indicate whether $activity is an array of objects or it's single object?

Comment: The root of your problem is the `true` in [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). It make sures that objects will be returned as associative arrays, so you can never see if something is an object.

Comment: one brute way is by checking the $activity whether it has 'ActivityLocation' index or not

Comment: If I use without true, it's also not possible to check if it's array or not, because it always returns it's object...

Comment: Because of your typo, `$activity` and `$activity2` are the same in your code.

Comment: I'd assume `$activity2 = $data['TrackResponse']['Shipment']['Package']['Activity'];` is a typo and you actually meant to write `$activity2 = $data['TrackResponse']['Shipment']['Package']['Activity2'];` ?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, and I corrected it, but it's still not working

Comment: That's because of what KIKO said in the first comment...you've decoded it in such a way that everything is an array. Decode as objects, and you'll have a chance

Comment: No, if it is an array it will tell you it is an array.

Comment: I tried $data = json_decode($json); but it always returns it's object, and never returns it's array

Comment: P.S. What kind of crummy API returns sometimes a object and sometimes an array? That's hopeless for the consumers. If you can, ask the JSON provider to fix their format so it always returns an array (e.g. if there is only one activity, it would return an array with 1 item in it). That will be a lot easier for you to process

Comment: UPS returns such....Activity could be an array or single object if if there is only single activity...

Comment: I agree, it is bad design to sometimes return a single object, and other times an array of objects.

Comment: `UPS returns such`...oh dear, that is poor quality from such a big company. But I guess in that case there is not much you can do about it. Anyway I showed you the solution below - doing exactly what KIKO suggested in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're decoding the JSON into a set of associative arrays, which means that `is_array` will always return true when used on any of the items in your decoded data, regardless of what the original JSON contained.

Decode it in the default format, and JSON objects will be turned into objects, while arrays will be turned into arrays. Then your tests will work as expected:

```
$data = json_decode($json);

$activity = $data->TrackResponse->Shipment->Package->Activity;
$activity2 = $data->TrackResponse->Shipment->Package->Activity2;
```

Working demo: https://3v4l.org/ljkLc

Background reading: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php